# Python MySQL query to CSV in memory

Tags: python, csv, mysql-python

I have a Python script which queries a DB and then emails the result. At the moment the script looks like this (please excuse my inexperience with Python)

```
db = mdb.connect(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name)
cur = db.cursor()
dbQuery =  ("SELECT A, B, C from table")
cur.execute (dbQuery)

rows = cur.fetchall()
fp = open(filename,'w')
myFile = csv.writer(fp, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
myFile.writerows(rows)
fp.close()

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = subject 
msg['From'] = email_from
msg['To'] = email_to
body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
body.attach(MIMEText(content, 'plain' ))
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open(filename, "rb").read())
Encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename) 
msg.attach(body)
msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
server.sendmail(email_from, email_to, msg.as_string())
```

I realise that it is inefficient to store the CSV file on disk, then close it and re-open to read. How can I do this all in memory? There is no requirement for the CSV to be saved as the data is all in the DB.

Comment: "I realise that it is inefficient to store the CSV file on disk", I doubt that this will ever be a bottleneck. I doubt it very much.

Comment: True, and the output of the query is pretty straightforward, but it just seems wrong if it's unnecessary. Would far rather it all happen in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cStringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO).

```
# create an in-memory "file":
f = cStringIO.StringIO()

# attach it to a writer:
w = csv.writer(f)

# write something:
w.writerows([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

# read the content:
content = f.getvalue()
```

```
'1,2,3\r\n4,5,6\r\n7,8,9\r\n'
```

Comment: Great thanks, that looks like the kind of thing! So if I want to refer to the file when I attach it to the MIME email, how would I do so?

Comment: You just need to use `part.set_payload(f.getvalue())`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile). This acts like a file, but is held in memory (unless it gets very large at which point it is converted transparently to a temporary file).

```
fp = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()
myFile = csv.writer(fp, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
myFile.writerows(rows)
fp.seek(0)   # rewind the file handle

...
part.set_payload(fp.read())
```